# FromUri in WebAPI action doesn't use JSON.NET JsonParameter to fetch parameters value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I'm working on a `GET` asp.net WebAPI action to accept a complex structure (`GET` is the requirement):

```
public class Input
{
    [JsonProperty("a")]
    public string PropA {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

and my method is:

```
public HttpActionResult Do([FromUri] Input model)
{
   ...
}
```

If I pass this object using POST withing body - it works perfectly fine. Json.NET is used to deserialize and I can pass an object like this: `{ 'a': '123' }`. But for `FromUri` (which is required because I have to use `GET`) I want to pass the following `GET` request and it doesn't work:

> ../api/v1/controller/do?a=123

As instead, it works like this:

> ../api/v1/controller/do?PropA=123

So instead of using my JsonProperty, the FromUri binder is using original property names.

Is there any way I can tweak the `FromUri` binder? Should I go with the custom one?

Comment: Are you looking for a custom media type formatter?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to force existing FromUri binder take advantage of json.net deserialization process

Comment: totally running into this wierd fromUri issue as well. I have a datetime property on my object that i want to come from the uri, but its failing to deserialize the datetime value, and it keeps saying its an invalid value. it even does this invalid value response if i put the field in directly into the controller parameters!